# How to find number of nulls in a table SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say that I have an employee table. And it has columns like name, salary, and age. If I want to check if there any nulls in the name. I gotta write

```
SELECT name FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE name IS NULL;
```

But what should I do to see the number of nulls each column has?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is:

```
select count(*) - count(name) as num_name_nulls,
       count(*) - count(col1) as num_col1_nulls,
       . . .
from employee;
```

However, what I do in this situation is just select the counts:

```
select count(*), count(name), count(col1), . . .
from employee;
```

Then I eyeball the result to see if the counts are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query but it depends on number of columns. It will give number of nulls each row has.

```
select 
  ((case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
   + (case when column2 is null then 1 else 0 end)
   ----------------------------------------
   ----------------------------------------
   +(case when columnN is null then 1 else 0 end))
 from TableName
```

For your case

```
select 
 ((case when name is null then 1 else 0 end)
 +(case when salary is null then 1 else 0 end)
 +(case when age is null then 1 else 0 end))
 from employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to see nulls for a column, you can apply conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name is null then 1 end) AS Name_NullCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN salary is null then 1 end) as salary_nullCount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN age is null then 1 end)  as age_nullcount
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find Null values per row from following query

```
SELECT 
(
 (CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
  ...
  ...
  +(CASE WHEN colName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
) AS sum_of_nulls
 FROM EMPLOYEE
 WHERE EmpId = 49
```

where colName is your Db Column Name

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    sum(case 
            when name is null then 1 
            when name is not null tehn 0 
        end) cname,
    sum(case 
            when salary is null then 1 
            when salary is not null then 0 
        end) csalary,
    ...
from employee
    limit 1;
```

Comment: count counts lines. It does not depend on the value 0 or 1. Sum adds 1 + 1 + 0 + ... Therefore, the value of the sum corresponds to the number of zero values.
limit 1 shows one line with values. If this is not done, all rows in the emploee table with the same sum values will be displayed.